# Scheduled Task and environment variables WITHOUT CMD /C

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, windows-task-scheduler

I need to run a task within Windows 2003 Task Scheduler however the command needs to access environment variables:

```
vlc.exe http://62.196.56.141:8080 --sout=#std{access=file,mux=raw,dst="C:\temp\streaming\%Date:~6,4%-%Date:~3,2%-%Date:~0,2%-RSMorning.mp3"}
```

While the above command will work when issued from a batch file or a command prompt, it will not expand correctly the variables when run from the Task Scheduler.

Someone would argue that this can be achieved using the CMD /C prefix, allowing the command to be launched within a command prompt, however as the task has to be forcibly terminated after a while, cmd.exe would be terminated in place of the invoked command (in this case, vlc.exe).

Any hint how to run the command without using a batch file or the command prompt, while inheriting correctly environment variables?

Comment: Are you sure you don't run [into this problem](http://superuser.com/questions/331077/accessing-environment-variables-in-a-scheduled-task)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd /c start "" vlc.exe http://62.196.56.141:8080 --sout=#std{access=file,mux=raw,dst="C:\temp\streaming\%Date:~6,4%-%Date:~3,2%-%Date:~0,2%-RSMorning.mp3"}
```

You can kill vlc with something like

```
taskkill /fi "imagename eq vlc.exe"
```

---

**EDIT** - Now that I fully understand your dilemma:

I'm pretty sure there is no simple solution that gives you access to the environment variables and also lets task scheduler kill vlc after time elapses. Your program knows nothing about environment variable expansion, so that must occur before `vlc.exe` is called. That is the job of `cmd.exe`. Unfortunately, Windows does not have true child processes, so if you launch `vlc.exe` via `cmd.exe`, then when you task scheduler kills `cmd.exe`, the `vlc.exe` process remains.

I believe you will have to write a script that launches `vlc.exe`, remembering the PID. The script would then wait your prescribed amount of time, and then kill vlc. Task scheduler can launch your script.

I believe you can do what you want with a batch script on Windows 2003, depending on which tools (commands) are available on that version of Windows.

TIMEOUT can be used to introduce a delay. For example, to wait 1 minute:

```
timeout 60 /nobreak >nul
```

WMIC can be used to launch a process and return the PID. See [Windows CMD Shell» Start a process and get its PID](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1495). I think the tricky part will be passing the quoted arguments, but it can be done. Read the entire thread.

Comment: Mate, as I wrote, using the CMD /C syntax will not allow to terminate properly the task after a given duration

Comment: @Riccardo - The CMD process will already be long gone. It closes as soon as START has launched vlc. What is to stop you from killing vlc? It will be its own process.

Comment: Task scheduler can optionally terminate the scheduled task after a given duration. Now, as the scheduled task is cmd.exe (with vlc.exe as a parameter), it will not be able to terminate vlc.exe when the duration time has ended

Comment: There will be multiple vlc.exe instances running at the same time! I would need the proper PID to properly kill the proper process....

Comment: @Riccardo - Fair enough. I understand your problem now.

Comment: as far as you are concerned, do you know why a process started from the scheduler cannot access environment variables? Maybe because there's no preprocessor that will handle them?

Comment: @Riccardo - Yes. See updated answer